# Using "exempli gratia" in essays

Tags: abbreviations, latin

Can I use "exempli gratia" (short for e.g.) in place of "for example?" If so, do I need to add any words to it to completely replace the phrase "for example?"

Comment: I don't think it will make you look at all smart. People will think you're a poser.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I guess I'll pass on the "exempli gratia"

Comment: No, it would not be a good idea. In general, Latin sounds affected, not smart. Just use *e.g.*, and say something smart in English. ;)

Comment: I sometimes like writing *free samples* in lieu of *e.g.*, just to see who appreciates the joke.

Comment: "exempli gratia" is NOT (short for e.g.), it is the other way round. After that, there are more things to know, please see the answers below.

Answer (score 13):

No, **don't** do that.

Unless, of course, you know that *gratiā* has a long *ā* at the end, and is therefore in the Ablative case; and you know that *exemplī* has a long *ī* at the end, and is therefore in the Genitive case; and you know what those cases mean, and you know how the phrase is constructed out of them.

In Latin. If you do know all that, then go right ahead.

Otherwise, don't try to ***sound*** smart; try to ***be*** smart. If you can't do that, don't try to fake it; just don't attract too much attention.

Executive Summary: ***e.g.*** is shorter.

Comment: Very well said! But why not just spell it out in English, *viz.* ‘for example’? ☺

Comment: Hm, *exemplī* could also be in the nominative plural instead of the genitive singular. Except that then it would have to be *grātiīs*, which is why you know that *exemplī* was actually in the genitive singular all along. Latin inflections are like a big algebraic puzzle sometimes, full of unknowns that you go zeroing in on as the pieces fall together, but with letters instead of numbers. You look at *bella* and wonder if that’s the adjective for pretty or the noun for war, and only the rest of the sentence will tell you. Look around for a *cāsus bellī*, or maybe even a *cāsus bellōrum*. ☺

Comment: Yeah, I tell my students that Latin color-codes all the words to mark the phrases, so word order isn't very important.

Comment: It also helps if they know that *exemplī < exemplum* is a 2ⁿᵈ-declension neuter, not a 2ⁿᵈ-declension masculine **exemplus*. You won’t pick that up from an unmarked *gratia*, although as you point out, knowing it’s actually *gratiā* not *gratia* steers them away from wondering whether it’s an nonexistent adjective in neuter plural agreement. The Romans seemed to do ok without macrons, just as I do with Italian words. I think they could hear it in their heads, so didn’t need the diacritics. Still, beginners are more apt to get Spanish *diabólico* right than the unmarked version in Italian.

Comment: They could hear it in their **ears**. Latin is syllable-timed, and long vowels were **longer** than short ones -- nobody knows by how much, but long vowels in languages with vowel length are normally held from about 1.4 to 1.8 times as long as short vowels. Macrons were invented later, for scholars speaking languages (like English) without real vowel length. Romans didn't even leave spaces between words, and used ALL CAPS all the time.

Comment: There’s also the musical pitch/tone theory from ancient Greek being present in archaic Latin, then that giving way to syllable length, then that giving way to syllable stress (which is actually tonal, but perhaps differently, and certainly not phonemically). Your point about Latin’s having been syllable-timed is a really important one. People underestimate the differences between stress- and syllable-timed languages. Compare how different syllable-timed Brazilian Portuguese sounds than does stress-timed European Portuguese. Vowel-length in Finnish is interesting, as is tone in Swedish.

Comment: @tchrist ROMANES EVNT DOMVS

Comment: @MetaEd Except that every one of those words in wrong, which is of course the joke. You need ROMANI in the vocative plural, ITE in the 2nd-person plural imperative, and DOMI in the (vestigial) locative (like RURI and HUMI). I’d have to check to make sure the somewhat special DOMI form hadn’t gone the way of most of the other locatives by the Augustan period, by which time they’d become ablatives.

Comment: When I taught [etymology](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/wow/), I spent more time on [Medieval Latin than Classical](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/wow/scans/Wow-7.pdf). Medieval Latin is stress-timed, and therefore the poetry sounds like poetry to English speakers, which Classical poetry doesn't because it's syllable-timed. And because it doesn't use rhyme; I was surprised when I found out that poetic rhyme as we know it wasn't invented until some time in the first half of the First Millenium AD.

Answer (score 5):

No, you don't need anything else. It can be used as is. But trying to "sound smart" in essays is usually counterproductive. I would not advise using it.

Comment: You presumed the abbreviation, not the full form. OP means to use the full form I believe.

Comment: I don't follow you Kris. The full form can be used without adding any other words to complete it.

Comment: I don't think we could use the full form in a regular English sentence as such, we only use the abbreviation. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Not common, and anachronistic but certainly possible. Consider: "Referring to Francis, he wrote, 'He has changed a great deal. Exempli gratia, he is happy... He knows everyone at Oxford.'" From the early part of the 20th century.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for an alternative to *for example*, you can use **for instance**. It's what I mostly use.

Answer (score 1):

On the odd chance that you actually meant to ask if you could use ***e.g.*** in place of *for example*, the answer is: Yes. Absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

**exempli gratia** comes from Latin. Your essay is in English and we use it in English with its short form **e.g.**, so **e.g.** has become more or less English word. So your question is like - "Am I going to look like smart panties using a Latin expression in essay in English". Most probably not- it depends in the way you are using it an it that case it is not a good idea. It is the same with **etc.** -it is also sometimes spelled **et caetera**, **et coetera** or **et cœtera** and is often abbreviated to **etc.**

My point is - we use **etc.** and **e.g.** in formal texts, but you are writing an essay - so most probably you are going to show that you don't know what is used in formal and informal text in English.